# Line element, metric tensor, integral and the sphere in fractional dimensions

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, general-relativity, dimension-theory-analysis, fractional-calculus

I have a question regarding fractional calculus, namely, what is the line element "$$ds^2 = g^{\mu\nu} dx_\mu dx_\nu$$ in fractional "n" dimensions?

I am aware of some formulas that give the surface of a sphere in general (fractional) dimensions $$S(n) = \frac{2\pi^\frac{n}{2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})} $$, also the different type of Differintegral formulas (such as the Riemann-Liouville formula): $$\int_a^b dx^\alpha f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_a^b (b-t)^{\alpha-1}f(t)dt$$.

Along this line, what is the function of the sphere? Should it be related maybe to the norm of a fractional dimensional vector?

In general I'm approaching the problem $$\int_a^b dx^{\alpha(x)} \sqrt{g(x)}f(x)$$, where $$\alpha(x)$$ is a "scale dependent" dimension factor, $$g(x)$$ should be the determinant of the metric tensor and $$f(x)$$ is a general function, and of course both $$g(x)=g_\alpha(x),f(x)=f_\alpha(x)$$ should be aware of the changing of $$\alpha(x)$$, thus I'm looking for a "fractional metric tensor". I couldn't really find much about this topic. I found some approaches to multifractional calculus, but so far nothing that helps with my main question.

Comment: The closest I can get is Hausdorff measures for sets of non-integer Hausdorff dimension. So Hausdorff $1$-dimensional measure would give you the "arclength" of the subset, if it exists.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you please elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: This is a deep and technical area, called geometric measure theory. For an introduction, I recommend Frank Morgan's *Geometric Measure Theory: A Beginner's Guide*. I know of no versions of the metric tensor or (semi-) Riemannian geometry in spaces of fractional Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, I took hold of the book. I like the first few pictures, very similar to what we think about quantum geometries. It will be an interesting reading!